# Написать Ansible playbook для windows

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, ansible-playbook

Есть следующая задача, которую я всё не могу решить:
***Для регламентной перезагрузки службы 1С требуется написать playbook на ansible с передачей в него входящего параметра (наименование службы).
Учесть возможность запуска playbook на разных ОС (Windows и Linux)***

Прочел много документаций и статьей, но так и не смог написать. Буду рад любым советам.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу мой кусок рабочего кода.

```yaml
    - name: Start Windows update service
      when:
        - ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
        - ansible_distribution_major_version == '10'
      become: yes
      become_method: runas
      become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
      win_service:
        name: wuauserv
        start_mode: auto
        state: started
```

Линукс отлично отсеивается по `ansible_system == 'Linux'`.